# Limit Amount of Pages users can create in Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

Is there a way to limit how many pages a user can make inside a custom post type? This would be pretty effective for commercial WP plugins and I am making one, but have come across a little problem and I would need to figure out how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my plugin [Bainternet Posts Creation Limits](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits/)
this plugin helps you to limit the number of posts/pages/custom post types each user can create on your site.
Its just what you need.

### Update

open up bapl.php and in bapl_limit_post_count function change on line 44:

```
if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {}else{ 
            if (isset($postt[$curent_type])){
                //$postt= bapl_getOptions('bapl');
                foreach ($postt as $key => $option){
                    if ($key = $curent_type) {
                        $ptname = $key;
                        $limit = $option;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //print_r($postt);
                $count_posts = count(get_posts(array('author'=>$current_user->ID,'post_type',$ptname)));

                if ($count_posts >= $limit){
                    //wp_die( __('You Can\'t Create any more pages of this type.') );
                    bapl_not_allowed();
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
```

to:

```
        if (isset($postt[$curent_type])){
            foreach ($postt as $key => $option){
                if ($key = $curent_type) {
                    $ptname = $key;
                    $limit = $option;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $count_posts = count(get_posts(array('author'=>$current_user->ID,'post_type',$ptname)));

            if ($count_posts >= $limit){

                bapl_not_allowed();
                exit;
            }
        }
```

this way the admin is limited too.

Next you will need to change bapl_getOptions function and set you defaults there.
And last you will probably wont to remove the admin control panel of this plugin so comment out line 69 were it says :

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'bapl_menu');
```

Comment: Excellent! I notice it says not to try it with the admin user, as they are never limited. Is there any way to override that? For a commercial plugin, for example my plugin, I will have different license types. The Single use license will only allow about 10 posts. The developer license will be unlimited. This will always be for the admin user.

Comment: Yes you can do that and its quite simple , i will look at the code when i get home and update my answer.